# Can't make ng-show work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I don't know if I am using the listener in the proper way. It works fine for other this, but I want that an HTML div shows when clicking, using ng-show. Am I missing something? Thanks!

```
 <div ng-show="infoActive">
    <h2>WHATEVER IS HERE</h2>
 </div>
```

And I have this as a triggering function. It actually works (there are more thing inside SelectHandler that work properly), but I can't make it show/hide my dive.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'select', selectHandler);

function selectHandler(e) {
    $scope.infoActive = !$scope.infoActive;
}
```

Comment: Need more context. What is $scope.infoActive - is it boolean? If so, where are you declaring it? Is your app setup correct - `ng-app`, `ng-controller` etc?

Comment: Maybe you can make a plunker.

Comment: @LJ.Wizard yes, it's quite a big application and everything works fine. It's just that I don't understand enough the behaviour of ng-show. What I have is a google chart, that triggers the function selectHandler() when clicking on it. There are more things inside that function in my code that work properly. But I don't know what I am doing wrong with ng-show.

Comment: `ng-show` evaluates the infoActive variable/expression. If it is true, it should show the `<div>`. What does your console.log give you when you run that function? With that you'll be able to determine if the error is in the logic, or if it's that it isn't binding to the view?

Comment: @LJ.Wizard I am using  console.log($scope.infoActive) and it switches true/false everytime I click, so the function works as I want. It looks like ng-show it's not evaluating that scope, or that I'm missing some ng-model... I don't know.

Comment: It's tough to say without seeing more of your code. Your function is declared in a controller right? It looks like your problem is that your logic isn't binding to the view. Make sure that you are declaring/initializing `$scope.infoActive` outside of that function, and that your `<div ng-show...>` is within the `ng-controller` section that has the same name as your controller where you declared this function.

Comment: @LJ.Wizard I made a Plunkr that shows more or less my problem, It reproduces the problem that I have. http://plnkr.co/edit/hvqnFfgxb4fuUM8y9aJX?p=preview     Thanks!!!
If it works, maybe it's a good idea to post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't binding your function to the scope. Change it to this and it will work:

```
$scope.selectHandler =  function selectHandler(e) {

          $scope.infoActive = !$scope.infoActive;
          console.log($scope.infoActive);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should init the value first

ex:

```
  <div ng-show="infoActive" >
   <h2>WHATEVER IS HERE</h2>
   </div>
<button ng-click="infoActive=!infoActive" >click it! </button>
```

your controller will like this

```
myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.infoActive= true;
}]);
```

Comment: This is not valid, I don't have a button. The function is triggered by the google chart, that's why I can't use a button...